# JQuery image as button fade-in effect not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to link an image on my webpage as a button linked to a JQuery function in order to fade out a specific screen area and replace it with text. My index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WWE Chicken</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/index.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <h1><a href = "wwe.html">WWE</a> VS <a href = "mma.html">MMA</a></h1>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $button = $("#buttons");
        function wweView(){
            $buttons = $button.find(".button");
            $wwe = $button.find("#wwe");

            setTimeout(function(){
                $buttons.fadeOut(function(){
                    $buttons.css("display:none;");
                    $wwe.fadeIn().css("display:block;color:white;")
                });

            }, 5000);
        }
    </script>



    <div id="buttons">
        <a href = "javascript: wweView()"><img class = "button" src="images/buttons/wwe.jpg" style = "margin-top: 20%;padding-bottom: 15px;" alt="WWE" width = "50%"/></a>
        <img class = "button" src="images/buttons/mma.jpg" alt="MMA" width = "50%"/>
    <div id = "wwe">
        <h2 class = "wtitle" id = "wweTitle">WWE</h2><ol>
            <li>Not as much hand combat</li>
            <li>Square ring</li>
            <li>Has finisher moves</li>
            <li>Has objects</li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div id = "mma">
        <h2 class = "wtitle" id="mmaTitle">MMA</h2>
        <ol>
            <li>More karate moves</li>
            <li>No nicknames</li>
            <li>Scripting is illegal</li>
            <li>More dangerous</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div id = "pictureSlide">
        <img src = "images/wrestlers/undertaker.jpeg" class = "active" alt = "The Undertaker" width = "100%" height = "500"/>
        <img src="images/wrestlers/tripleh.jpe" alt="Triple H" width = "500" height = "500"/>
        <img src="images/wrestlers/lita.jpg" alt="Lita" width = "500" height = "500"/>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
         function swapImages(){
      var $active = $('#pictureSlide .active');
      var $next = ($('#pictureSlide .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#pictureSlide .active').next() : $('#pictureSlide img:first');
      $active.fadeOut(function(){
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
      setInterval('swapImages()', 5000);
    });

    </script>










</body>
</html>
```

And my css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

h1{
    color: #EBEBEB; 
    text-align: center;
}

body{
    background-image: url("../images/swirlyred.jpeg");
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
}

a{
    color: red;
}


#differences{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #ff0000;

}

#buttons{
    display:block;
    width: 40%;
    height:500px;
    float:right;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}

#buttons img{
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;

}

#wwe{
    display: none;
}
#mma{
    display: none;
}



footer{
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;

}
footer p{
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#pictureSlide{

    background-color: black;
    width:50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;

}

#pictureSlide img{
    display: none;

}

#pictureSlide img.active{
  display:block;
}
```

Please tell me where I am going wrong. I see nothing in the JavaScript console after clicking the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```js
 $button = $("#buttons");
          function wweView(){
            $buttons = $button.find(".button");
            //...
          }
```

To

```js
function wweView(){
             $button = $("#buttons");
             $buttons = $button.find(".button");
         //...
        }
```

Comment: However, my fade in only happens after 5 seconds??

Comment: And fade out doesn't happen at all

Comment: because you put the fadeIn inside a setTimeout with 5 seconds(5000 ms).

Comment: How do I fade out. hold for five seconds, and fade back in?

Comment: I can't find a way to do it with JQuery

Answer (score 0):

You were initializing the variable  `$button = $("#buttons");` before the documentReady() function, so jquery still was not loaded, so it had no effect. Just put it inside of your weeView() so that it gets initialized upon invocation, like this:

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

h1{
    color: #EBEBEB; 
    text-align: center;
}

body{
    background-image: url("../images/swirlyred.jpeg");
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
}

a{
    color: red;
}


#differences{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #ff0000;

}

#buttons{
    display:block;
    width: 40%;
    height:500px;
    float:right;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
}

#buttons img{
    display: block;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;

}

#wwe{
    display: none;
}
#mma{
    display: none;
}



footer{
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 70%;

}
footer p{
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#pictureSlide{

    background-color: black;
    width:50%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;

}

#pictureSlide img{
    display: none;

}

#pictureSlide img.active{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>WWE Chicken</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "css/index.css"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <h1><a href = "wwe.html">WWE</a> VS <a href = "mma.html">MMA</a></h1>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        function wweView(){
            $button = $("#buttons");
            
            $buttons = $button.find(".button");
            $wwe = $button.find("#wwe");
            
          

            setTimeout(function(){
                $buttons.fadeOut(function(){
                    $buttons.css("display:none;");
                    $wwe.fadeIn().css("display:block;color:white;")
                });

            }, 1000);
        }
    </script>



    <div id="buttons">
        <a href = "javascript: wweView()"><img class = "button" src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-WfUr-Occ-7k/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAF8/8AMaJVL6rwc/w48-c-h48/photo.jpg" style = "margin-top: 20%;padding-bottom: 15px;" alt="WWE" width = "50%"/></a>
        <img class = "button" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1773619596/image_normal.jpg" alt="MMA" width = "50%"/>
    <div id = "wwe">
        <h2 class = "wtitle" id = "wweTitle">WWE</h2><ol>
            <li>Not as much hand combat</li>
            <li>Square ring</li>
            <li>Has finisher moves</li>
            <li>Has objects</li>
        </ol>
    </div>

    <div id = "mma">
        <h2 class = "wtitle" id="mmaTitle">MMA</h2>
        <ol>
            <li>More karate moves</li>
            <li>No nicknames</li>
            <li>Scripting is illegal</li>
            <li>More dangerous</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
    </div>


    <div id = "pictureSlide">
        <img src = "images/wrestlers/undertaker.jpeg" class = "active" alt = "The Undertaker" width = "100%" height = "500"/>
        <img src="images/wrestlers/tripleh.jpe" alt="Triple H" width = "500" height = "500"/>
        <img src="images/wrestlers/lita.jpg" alt="Lita" width = "500" height = "500"/>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
         function swapImages(){
      var $active = $('#pictureSlide .active');
      var $next = ($('#pictureSlide .active').next().length > 0) ? $('#pictureSlide .active').next() : $('#pictureSlide img:first');
      $active.fadeOut(function(){
      $active.removeClass('active');
      $next.fadeIn().addClass('active');
      });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      // Run our swapImages() function every 5secs
      setInterval('swapImages()', 5000);
    });

    </script>


</body>
</html>
```